# Vectorizing a for-loop containing an if-else statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, vector, vectorization

For my program, I have to write a script that identifies clusters based on the distance "locuslim", which is the maximum distance allowed. I got a slow for-loop working as desired, but I have some trouble vectorizing it to optimize the runtime.
"s" is the iterator for all strains being compared and "i" is to iterate over rows. Col is to create new columns, each strain getting a new column.
Especially the ifelse seems to be the issue...
The for-loop (as function):

```
clusterfunc <- function (TABLE11_4){
  for (s in levels(Strains)){
    message(s) # Just to see the progress while running
    locus <- min(TABLE11_4$dist[TABLE11_4$dist>0 & TABLE11_4$Organism.q==s], na.rm=TRUE) # The minimal distance between two items
    locuslim <- 3*locus # Maximal distance allowed
    col <- paste("Cluster",s,sep=".")
    TABLE11_4 <- TABLE11_4 %>% group_by(Organism.h) %>% arrange(Rev.gr) %>% mutate(col=ifelse(lead(dist)<=locuslim,1,2))
    TABLE11_4 <- TABLE11_4 %>% group_by() %>% arrange(Rev.gr)
    TABLE11_4$dist[is.na(TABLE11_4$dist)] <- 0 # Eliminate NAs by making them 0
    c=1
    for(i in 1:nrow(TABLE11_4)){
      if(TABLE11_4$dist[i]<=locuslim){
        TABLE11_4$col[i] <- c # Set clusternumber it belongs to
      }
      else{
        TABLE11_4$col[i] <- c+1 # Set next clusternumber it belongs to
        c <- c+1 # Go to next cluster
      }
    }
    setnames(TABLE11_4,"col",col)
  }
  return(TABLE11_4)
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using `apply` instead of the inner for loop for performance. If it wasn't for the `c <- c+1` in your `else` then that could be really nicely vectorised with the `ifelse` function. Also, `c` as a variable name is a bad choice because a function called `c` already exists in R.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the suggestions. I finally found a way to perform the same actions while taking a lot less time, but than you anyways!